# Patch C/C++ function to just return without execution

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc

I want to avoid one system function executing in a large project. It is impossible to redefine it or add some `ifdef` logic. So I want to patch the code to just the `ret` operation.

The functions are:

```
void __cdecl _wassert(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, unsigned);
```

and:

```
void __dj_assert(const char *, const char *, int, const char *) __attribute__((__noreturn__));
```

So I need to patch the first one on `Visual C++` compiler, and the second one on `GCC` compiler.

Can I just write the `ret` instruction directly at the address of the `_wassert`/`__dj_assert` function, for x86/x64?

**UPDATE:**

I just wanna modify function body like this:

```
*_wassert = `ret`;
```

Or maybe copy another function body like this:

```
void __cdecl _wassert_emptyhar_t *, const wchar_t *, unsigned)
{
}

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(void*); i++) {
    ((char*)_wassert)[i] = ((char*)_wassert_empty
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I really don't understand why there are so many objections against silent `asserts`. In fact, there is no asserts in the `RELEASE` mode, but nobody cares. I just want to be able turning on/off the asserts in the `DEBUG` mode.

Comment: Seems a dubious requirement. How about fixing the code that is triggering the assertion failures instead?

Comment: This looks like the back end support functions for the [`assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) makro. Code that triggers an `assert()` is **broken** (that's the purpose of `assert()`), and needs to be fixed. Patching the `assert()` to no-op doesn't fix anything. Besides, code compiled with `NDEBUG` defined shouldn't execute `assert()` in the first place. So I'm with jxh on this one; your requirement is dubious at best.

Comment: Asserts are really broken, in release there are no problem with asserts. NO asserts - no problems. But in debug there are tons of crashing asserts. Modifying code is not possible right now - megabytes of code...

Comment: If modifying source code is not possible, you should question your development process and work on improving that.

Comment: Typically when people bother writing asserts it's because the code breaks badly if such preconditions are violated... Your program seeming to work in release mode tells nothing about its correctness - I have worked on lots of projects with memory errors that seemed to work fine most of time - but they crashed randomly with "impossible" errors; the solution was *not* to disable checks and hope for the best, but enabling each and every possible assertion/tool (regular asserts, debug mode, STL debug, valgrind, debug allocators,...) and *fix* the friggin' bugs.

Comment: You should motivate more your question, and tell more about your software and team (size of software in million lines of code, number of person in the team, what C++ standard is followed, what libraries are used, **why cannot you use and have to avoid `assert`**, etc...). So please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch added update2 to question

Comment: Silenced asserts are like broken thermometers, they should be removed outright or replaced by unbroken ones on a case-by-case basis, or nursing the patient back to health is going to be even more of a pain in the ass. Also, please tell us what company you work for, so that we may never buy their software.

Comment: @Medinoc this is not on my main job (thanks, God). Just helping friend to fix bugs when have enough time. Sure, terrible things happens, looks like a crime in software development :)

Comment: Help your friend by convincing them to improve their work habits. Disabling or avoiding `assert` is plain non-sense. Explain them what *technical debt* is.

Comment: "I really don't understand why there are so many objections against silent asserts. In fact, there is no asserts in the RELEASE mode, but nobody cares." The original idea behind asserts being disabled in release mode is that such checks are (1) costly and (2) should be triggered only in case of bugs (typically when preconditions are violated), which should be absent in released software. Notice that since most checks are actually almost free and in the real world software is definitely not bug-free even when released, many people actually ship release builds *with assertions enabled*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for your particular processor [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) and system [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for x86 & x86-64 calling conventions.

Some calling conventions require more than a single `ret` machine instruction in the epilogue, and you have to count with that. BTW, code of some function usually resides in a *read-only* [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment), and you'll need some dirty tricks to patch it and write inside it.

You could compile a no-op function of the same signature, and ask the compiler to show the emitted assembler code (e.g. with `gcc -O -Wall -fverbose-asm -S`  if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....)

On Linux you might use dynamic linker [`LD_PRELOAD` tricks](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/). If using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you might perhaps consider customizing it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), but I don't think it is worthwhile in your particular case...

However, **you** apparently **have some [`assert`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_assert.htm) failure. It is very unlikely that your program could continue without any [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).** So practically speaking, your program will very likely crash elsewhere with your proposed "fix", and you'll lose more of your time with it.
Better take enough time to correct the original bug, and improve your development process. Your way is postponing a critical bug correction, and you are extremely likely to spend more time avoiding that bug fix than dealing with it properly  (and finding it *now*, not later) as you should. **Avoid increasing your [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt)** and making your code base even more buggy and rotten.

My feeling is that you are going nowhere (except to a big failure) with your approach of patching the binary to avoid `assert`-s. You should find out why there are violated, and improve the code (either remove the obsolete `assert`, or improve it, or correct the bug elsewhere that `assert` has detected).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but really this asserts are not used for several years. And project is too large to remove or fix all asserts. I just wanna disable all of them in debug.

Comment: If you believe some `assert`-s are obsolete, you should discuss that in your team and remove them... Otherwise, the code is increasingly rotten.

Comment: Most of team members prefer to comment asserts with regexp :)

Comment: @k06a: this increases the technical debt. The project seems likely to fail or ask you a lot of overtime boring work. Perhaps you should look for another job if you cannot decrease that technical debt.

Comment: Incidentally, you simply cannot patch just `__dj_assert` to return, as it's marked as `noreturn`, so the compiler may as well have replaced the `call` instruction with a `jmp` (=> you have no address to return to) or have elided the caller cleanup code from the call sites (=> so if you do a `ret` the caller finds the stack completely messed up).

Answer (score 3):

On Gnu/Linux you can use the `--wrap`option like this:

```
gcc source.c -Wl,--wrap,functionToPatch -o prog
```

and your source must add the wrapper function:

```
void *__wrap_functionToPatch () {} // simply returns
```

Parameters and return values as needed for your function.

Comment: Project is too large and too complex to add this option to all makefiles. Thats why I prefer live function patching.

Comment: @k06a: read [the mythical man month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month); you'll realize that your proposed binary patching route will take your *more time* than understanding the real bug and fixing it.

Comment: @k06a Your project is to large to do it with `ifdef`. Your Makefiles are to complex to add a single linking option to it? I believe you have definitely a other very big problem! And only as an addition: If your method you want to patch is known by the compiler, remember it will be inlined somewhere which never can patched or wrapped.